# error starting tomee server from eclipse servers tab

Tags: apache, eclipse-juno, apache-tomee

My OS is win 7 ultimate 32 bit
After installing JDK 7u9, eclipse Juno (4.2) SR1 for Java EE
and finally adding into it the new server
Apache TomEE 1.5.0 October 2nd, 2012 apache-tomee-1.5.0-webprofile.zip
(using eclipse wizard to add new servers and choosing tomcat 7 profile and then the directory where it's installed)

i'm getting the following console error

```
...
...
...
nov 13, 2012 8:07:53 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBContextConfig processAnnotationsFile
SEVERE: OpenEJBContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile: failed.
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 32
C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\testtomee01\WEB-INF\classes
                            ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
...
...
...
```

the server, eventually seems to start but then you get the 404 error on every page under `http://localhost:8080/`

tomEE installation directory is `C:\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.5.0`
eclipse installation directory is `C:\eclipse`
and java jre under `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the current Windows release is broken. You'll have to download a fixed version as suggested in the bug report found here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-436

The 1.5.1 snapshots are available for download here: [1.5.1-SNAPSHOT](http://openejb.apache.org/cgi-bin/builds.cgi/apache-tomee/1.5.1-SNAPSHOT/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, should have been fixed and included in the next release (1.5.1).
FYI, it should be available next week.

Jean-Louis