# Apache TomEE (Tomcat Java EE) won't start on Windows (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3)

Tags: apache-tomee

I get the following error when trying to start TomEE on Windows:

> SEVERE: OpenEJBContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile: failed.
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape
>   sequence near index 3
>   C:\Users\Ed\moba\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\OpenJPATest\WEB-INF\classes
>   ^     at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2177)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:1952)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1885)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1133)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)     at
>   java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2146)   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBContextConfig.getSubPackage(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1296)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBContextConfig.webConfig(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just answered a similar question here: [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367807/error-starting-tomee-server-from-eclipse-servers-tab)

To reiterate:

> It looks like the current Windows release is broken. You'll have to
>   download a fixed version as suggested in the bug report found here:
>   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-436
>
> The 1.5.1 snapshots are available for download here: 
>   [1.5.1-SNAPSHOT](http://openejb.apache.org/cgi-bin/builds.cgi/apache-tomee/1.5.1-SNAPSHOT/)